# Change a slide visibility in Reveal.js Markdown presentation

Tags: reveal.js

In Reveal.js a slide can be hidden with `data-visibility="hidden"` attribute like this:

```
<section>Slide 1</section>
<section data-visibility="hidden">Slide 2</section>
<section>Slide 3</section>
```

But how can I hide a slide in Markdown presentation?

```
<section data-markdown>
  <textarea data-template>
    ## Slide 1
    ---
    ## Slide 2
    ---
    ## Slide 3
  </textarea>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution. To hide a markdown slide we can use a [slide attribute](https://revealjs.com/markdown/#slide-attributes) like this:

```
<!-- .slide: data-visibility="hidden" -->
```

Consider the example from the question:

```
<section data-markdown>
  <textarea data-template>
    ## Slide 1
    ---
    <!-- .slide: data-visibility="hidden" -->
    ## Slide 2
    ---
    ## Slide 3
  </textarea>
</section>
```